# Handling of missing thin space character in LuaHBTeX

Tags: fonts, luahbtex

LuaHBTeX has different handling of missing thin space glyph in fonts from previous luatex or xetex versions.

```
\documentclass[margin=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Courgette Regular}
\begin{document}
foo bar\,bazμ 
\end{document}
```

There is a thin space (U+202F) between `foo` and `bar`, and the font is missing glyphs for this and for the mu character.

Rendering in HBTeX (version 1.12.0 from Debian's TeX Live, with luaotfload version 2020-02-02 3.12):

[image]

Rendering in xelatex:

[image]

It seems that some special handling of missing whitespace characters has been removed, which may be surprising to users.

Comment: No nothing has been removed. Previously missing chars were simply ignored, now they insert a notdef glyph. You can revert to the old behaviour with `[RawFeature={notdef=false}]`

Comment: Also adding `[Renderer=HarfBuzz]` to `\setmainfont` generates the same output you got with XeTeX.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: it seems to me that there was some special handling of this thin space character, because the missing mu glyph was rendered differently from the missing U+202F glyph. With `notdef=false`, both the cross glyphs disappear whereas with older version, only the thin space disappeared.

Comment: @EricMarsden If I try your example with TeXLive 2019, I get the same behavour as TeXLive 2020. In TeXLive 2018, I get the same output as with `notdef=false`. I would be *very* surprised if any non-HarfBuzz version of luaotfload gave the same as the XeTeX version.

Comment: My memory must be incorrect concerning the behaviour of older luatex versions, my apologies; I have updated the question. So it seems to be xetex and the HarfBuzz renderer that have some special handling of this missing U+202F glyph.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The missing characters just used to be ignored (with warning in the log file).

You can make adjustments for them, so they appear as themselves if the font has the glyphs, or provide a substitution.

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}

\setmainfont{Libertinus Serif}

\newcommand{\substitutechar}[2]{% #1 = character, #2 = substitution
  \newunicodechar{#1}{\iffontchar\font`#1 #1\else#2\fi}%
}

\substitutechar{^^^^202f}{\,}
\substitutechar{μ}{\ensuremath{\mu}}

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

foo bar\,bazμ

\showoutput

\end{document}
```

If I compile the example, I get

```latex
....\TU/LibertinusSerif(0)/m/n/10 f
....\TU/LibertinusSerif(0)/m/n/10 o
....\kern0.07 (font)
....\TU/LibertinusSerif(0)/m/n/10 o
....\TU/LibertinusSerif(0)/m/n/10
....\TU/LibertinusSerif(0)/m/n/10 b
....\TU/LibertinusSerif(0)/m/n/10 a
....\TU/LibertinusSerif(0)/m/n/10 r
....\kern1.66672
....\TU/LibertinusSerif(0)/m/n/10 b
....\TU/LibertinusSerif(0)/m/n/10 a
....\TU/LibertinusSerif(0)/m/n/10 z
....\TU/LibertinusSerif(0)/m/n/10 μ
```

If I remove the `\setmainfont` line, the font will be Latin Modern Roman that, like your Courgette font, lacks both U+202F and U+03BC, I get

```latex
....\TU/lmr/m/n/10 f
....\TU/lmr/m/n/10 o
....\kern0.28 (font)
....\TU/lmr/m/n/10 o
....\kern1.66672
....\TU/lmr/m/n/10 b
....\TU/lmr/m/n/10 a
....\TU/lmr/m/n/10 r
....\kern1.66672
....\TU/lmr/m/n/10 b
....\TU/lmr/m/n/10 a
....\TU/lmr/m/n/10 z
....\mathon
....\OML/cmm/m/it/10 ^^V
....\mathoff
```

that shows the substitutions have been performed.

Comment: Thanks, perhaps a package that put together all imaginable character substitutions of this form might be useful, especially for users of free fonts that tend to have more missing glyphs than commercial fonts.